# Generate random number with constraint in java

Tags: java, performance, random

I need to generate a random integer with Java but random in a one sided bounded specific range. For example, a range from 15+ means that the only constraint is that the lowest value the integer can take is 15.

Comment: Surely you mean 15 to Integer.MAX_VALUE? I'm hoping now I've reminded you an Integer has a maximum value, you will realise the solution yourself. ;)

Comment: Well, we now know what you want, but what have _you_ tried so far to generate such a number?

Comment: Oh, OP. Could you clarify some edge cases: Can it have an upper bound? e.g. 15-, and are negatives valid outputs?

Comment: Do you mean a *uniform* distribution? That's pretty simple. If you're talking about truncating another distribution, like the normal distribution, that's more interesting.

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int min=15;
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((2147483647 - min) + 1)+ min;
```

Comment: Two one four seven... what? Please use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @maaartinus that's good idea .honestly i didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple `randomInRange` function like this:

Yyou want to create the `Random` object only once so it doesn't have to re-seed each time you call the `randomInRange()` function.

```
Random rand;

// ...

// where you initialize stuff (for example the class constructor)

rand = new Random();

// ...

int randomInRange(int min, int max) {
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

If you want to only have the minimum value, maybe create another method like:

```
int randomFrom(int min) {
    return randomInRange(min, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

I suggest you make a separate `Utilities` class that will contain these methods as `static` and you can call them by saying `Utilities.randomInRange()` 
You can of course make them `static` in your class as well if these are the only utility methods you will need

Comment: Didn't not copy properly from ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: @GuyFlavell care to elaborate?

Comment: @Aeshang this is a standard way of generating random numbers in java between a certain range....

Comment: @GuyFlavell I understand that but it is just a simple answer. I will edit that part now

Comment: @nem use static in you method ... :P that is why i said didn't copy properly ;)

Comment: @nem you may still get hate from answering this question which appears to be simple enough to be a homework. ;) (but not from me)

Comment: @GuyFlavell ok... don't really understand you guys, especially the approval of the second answer that is pretty much equivalent to mine :) as far as creating the new `Random` each time, I realize that is not efficient

Comment: The second answer is different in that it doesn't attempt to provide a full solution, if the new Random() is contained in the same method it would still be wrong. But it is sufficiently incomplete to be ambiguous. :) I am happy to upvote you when you edit this to be correct. :) It's meant as guidance, not punishment. :)

Comment: @GuyFlavell it makes sense, just wasn't aware of the whole "not providing complete answers" but ok, cool... I though giving a step by step answer is more beneficial than a hint. However, I see your point. thanks for the advice then :)

Comment: @Aeshang I don't understand why something relatively simple and well-know like this has to be copied :)
`static` isn't included cause I provided the simplest answer... Here, I added it, just for you :P